# Gradient Layer not showing on UIButton

Tags: swift, uibutton, swift4, cagradientlayer

I am trying to create a custom UIButton that i can use throughout my application. I would like to apply a gradient as its background however the gradient is not showing up using this very simple Code. 
It would be very helpful if someone could point out my mistake in the code below.

```
class GradientBtn: UIButton {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        themeConfig()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        themeConfig()
    }

    private func themeConfig() {
        //shadow
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0

        //titletext
        setTitleColor(Theme.colorWhite, for: .normal)
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Theme.fontAvenir, size: 18)

        //rounded corners
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height / 2

        //gradient
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.colors = [Theme.colorlightBlue, Theme.colorMidBlue]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
gradientLayer.colors = [Theme.colorlightBlue, Theme.colorMidBlue]
```

with

```
gradientLayer.colors = [Theme.colorlightBlue.cgColor, Theme.colorMidBlue.cgColor]
```

---

And it's always good to add

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sh_Khan is right about the `CGColor` references, but a few additional refinements:

1. Rather than adding the gradient as a sublayer, make it the [`layerClass`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622626-layerclass) of the `UIButton`. This makes animations much better (e.g. if the button changes size on device rotation).

   When you do this, remove all attempts to set the `frame` of the `gradientLayer`.
2. In `layoutSubviews`, you’ll no longer need to update the `gradientLayer.frame`, so remove that entirely, but you do want to put your corner rounding there.
3. It’s extremely unlikely to ever matter, but when you set `layer.cornerRadius` (or any property of the view, its layer, or that layer's sublayers), you should never refer to `self.frame`. The `frame` of the view is the `CGRect` in the superview’s coordinate system. Only refer to the view’s `bounds` within the subclass; never its `frame`.

Thus:

```
class GradientBtn: UIButton {
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self }
    private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { return layer as! CAGradientLayer }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        themeConfig()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        themeConfig()
    }
    
    private func themeConfig() {
        //shadow
        layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        
        //titletext
        setTitleColor(Theme.colorWhite, for: .normal)
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Theme.fontAvenir, size: 18)
        
        //gradient
        gradientLayer.locations = [0, 1]
        gradientLayer.colors = [Theme.colorlightBlue, Theme.colorMidBlue].map { $0.cgColor }
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        layer.cornerRadius = min(bounds.height, bounds.width) / 2
    }
}
```